# Create Array of Objects using array.push(obj) error

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Attempting to create an array of objects from 2 arrays of different lengths. One array has the `key` values and the other is an array of arrays which stores the `values` for each key:

```
var keyArray = ["key1","key2","key3","key4"];
var valuesArray = [{"value1","value2","value3","value4"},{"value5","value6","value7","value8"},{"value9","value10","value11","value12"}];
```

I am trying to create a new `results` array with each `foo` object:

```
var currentKey; // temp variable
var currentValue; // temp variable
var foo = {}; 
var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < keyArray.length; j++) {
    currentKey = keyArray[j];
    currentValue = valuesArray[i][j];
    foo[currentKey] = currentValue;
  }
results.push(foo);
}
console.log(results); // results = [{key1: "value9", key2: "value10", key3: "value11", key4: "value12"},{key1: "value9", key2: "value10", key3: "value11", key4: "value12"},{key1: "value9", key2: "value10", key3: "value11", key4: "value12"}]
```

Expected Results:

```
console.log(results) // results = [{key1: "value1", key2: "value2", key3: "value3", key4: "value4"},{key1: "value5", key2: "value6", key3: "value7", key4: "value8"},{key1: "value9", key2: "value10", key3: "value11", key4: "value12"}]
```

For some reason, only the last item in `valuesArray` (`{value9,value10,value11,value12}`) gets pushed into the `results` array

Comment: `valuesArray` contains invalid objects.

Comment: You have to create a new `foo` for each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: @user9397809 Not sure why someone downvoted your question as you tagged it correctly, provided your code and made an attempt, so I upvoted your question to offset it. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the same `foo` object all the time. You should reassign a new object to `foo` on each iteration of the outer loop:

```js
var keyArray = ["key1","key2","key3","key4"];
var valuesArray = [["value1","value2","value3","value4"
],["value5","value6","value7","value8"],["value9","value10","value11","value12"]];

var currentKey; // temp variable
var currentValue; // temp variable
var foo; 
var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
  foo = {};
  for(var j = 0; j < keyArray.length; j++) {
    currentKey = keyArray[j];
    currentValue = valuesArray[i][j];
    foo[currentKey] = currentValue;
  }
  results.push(foo);
}
console.log(results);
```

You can also use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the values array, and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate an object for each sub-array:

```js
var keyArray = ["key1","key2","key3","key4"];
var valuesArray = [["value1","value2","value3","value4"
],["value5","value6","value7","value8"],["value9","value10","value11","value12"]];

var results = valuesArray.map(function(s) {
  return keyArray.reduce(function(o, k, i) {
    o[k] = s[i];
  
    return o;
  }, {});
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more concise approach and map the objects with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for a single object and return an array of objects.

```js
var keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3", "key4"],
    values = [["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"], ["value5", "value6", "value7", "value8"], ["value9", "value10", "value11", "value12"]],
    result = values.map(a => Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With functions `reduce` and `map`.

```js
var keyArray = ["key1","key2","key3","key4"];
var valuesArray = [["value1","value2","value3","value4"],["value5","value6","value7","value8"],["value9","value10","value11","value12"]];

var result = valuesArray.map(a => (a.reduce((a,c,i) => ({...a, ...{ [keyArray[i]] : c}}), {})));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```